# How to solve conditional linear recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

How to solve conditional linear recurrence??
for example,

```
f[1]=m;  
f[i]=f[i-1]*m; if i is even
f[i]=(f[i-1]-2)*2 +2 if i is odd
```

calculate    f[n]
if its just a simple linear recurrence, f[n] can be calculated in O(log N) time but how to handle two different recurrence??

Answer (score 2):

```
f[i] = (f[i - 2] * m - 2) * 2 + 2 if i is odd
f[i] = ((f[i - 2] -2) * 2 + 2) * m if i is even
```

Now solve the two recurences separately. I substituted your formulas in one another with the aim to get even and odd indices depend only on the same parity.

Comment: It should be  f[i]=((f[i-2]-2)*2+2)*m if i is even.......any way thanks for approach...........